# Python - How to get all documents saved in collection from MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I saved all my images in path into MongoDB. Now I want to display all images by getting all the image path in the collection. 
I can get all documents from the collection but when I get the 'path_name', it would only show one result in command prompt.

my MongoDB

```
{
    "_id": "5a093e83ccd7462a086132da",
    "pics_name": "Pics1",
    "path_name": "static/image/greeting/01.jpg"
}
```

This is Views.py

```
import pymongo
from project.Greetings import GreetingsImg

@view_config(route_name='testtest', renderer='templates/testtest.jinja2')
def testtest(request):

    greet = GreetingsImg(request)

    greetall = greet.get_all(all)
    for i in greetall:
        print(i)

    allgreetings = i['path_name']
    print(allgreetings)

return {'allgreetings':allgreetings}
```

This is Greetings.py

```
class GreetingsImg(object):

def __init__(self, request):
    self.collection_greetings_img = request.db['greetings_img']

def get_by_name(self, pics_name):
    return self.collection_greetings_img.find({ "pics_name": pics_name})

def get_by_path(self, path_name):
    return self.collection_greetings_img.find({ "path_name": path_name})

def get_all(self,all):
    return self.collection_greetings_img.find()
```

Comment: Because `i` contains only the last iteration. If you expect an array of values to output, then use `map` or `.append()` on an existing array as you iterate the loop.

Comment: but if I make `x = []` when I add `x.append(i) print(i)`, `x` is a list and I cannot just retrieve the path only.

Comment: `x.append(i['path_name'])`. The `.find()` returns a list, which I thought you should know since you put it on `get_all()`. If you just want the one value for each in the list, then that's all you return. Alternately `find({},{ "path_name": 1 })` returns only that field of each document.